# Condition variable to pause a thread after finishing a particular task (in Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements

I am implementing a GUI for a program that builds and modifies a big graph for a bus-routing problem.

I want to have a Play-button, that should start the simulations (create a new thread simThread that executes a simulate()-method, which is pretty much an infinite loop calling a method modifyGraph() over and over again).

I also want a Pause-button, that when pressed causes the simThread to wait, but not UNTIL it has finished its current call to modifyGraph()). This is because during modifyGraph(), the graph is often in a state that shouldn't be plotted. When I press Play again, simThread should ideally continue where it was.

I am relatively new to threading in general and in Python in particular, but I have a feeling Condition Variables are the way to go. Anybody knows how to go about this?

Comment: Have also a look at the documentation for [event objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects)

Answer (score 1):

If your simThread looks something like this:

```
class simThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            modifyGraph()
```

You can introduce an event to unpause like this:

```
class simThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.unpaused = threading.Event()
        self.unpaused.set()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            modifyGraph()
            unpaused.wait()
```

You would use this functionality like this:

```
thread = simThread()
thread.start()
thread.unpaused.clear()
[...]
thread.unpaused.set()
```

If you think an event called `unpaused` is a bit awkward, you can also have an additional boolean variable `pause` that you initially set to `False`. In the thread, you would check if it is `True` and then wait for an unpause event. So something like this:

```
class simThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pause = False
        self.unpause = threading.Event()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            modifyGraph()
            if self.pause:
                unpause.wait()

    def pause(self):
        self.unpause.clear()
        self.pause = True

    def unpause(self):
        self.pause = False
        self.unpause.set()

thread = simThread()
thread.start()
thread.pause()
thread.unpause()
```

The reason why you should use an event instead of just having another while loop spinning on `self.pause` is to avoid wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: Thanks so much! I already made an ugly work-around like this:

After having completed a call to modifyGraph() a boolean stopFlag is examined. If stopFlag is True, return is called (so that the thread terminates). 

simulate()
    while True:
        modifyGraph()
        if self.stopFlag:
            return

When I then press the Pause Button, the main thread sets the stopFlag from False to True and calls simThread.join(). 

onPause()
    self.stopFlag=False
    self.simThread.join()
    
I feel like your approach is better though since it actually makes the thread pause instead of terminate.